# Unable to connect with Client due to Connect(Timeout) Error

Tags: rust, https, actix-web

I'm trying to make an https request to a third party API from my Actix Web Server. I'm using `awc::Client` to make the request. I'm running the server on Windows 10 with the `openssl` features enabled in the `Cargo.toml` file.

Here is the code that is running:

```
...

let client = Client::default();
let response = client.get("https://www.google.com")
    .set_header("User-Agent", "Actix-web")
    .send().await;

info!("Response: {:?}", response.unwrap());
```

Whenever I try to unwrap the result, I get this exception:

`thread 'actix-rt:worker:0' panicked at 'called Result::unwrap() on an Err value: Connect(Timeout)'`

How come I'm getting this exception? I'm guessing it's a configuration issue, but am unsure.

Answer (score 0):

If your latency is too high, try setting the timeout manually:

```
/*...*/

let client = Client::builder()
    .timeout(Duration::from_secs(5))
    .finish();

let response = client.get("https://www.google.com")
    .set_header("User-Agent", "Actix-web")
    .send().await;

info!("Response: {:?}", response.unwrap());

/*...*/
```

Comment: I've tried increasing the latency and that did not resolve my problem. I tried using the reqwest crate in a separate binary and I was able to make the request successfully. I am starting to think it might be an issue with the actix_web framework.

Comment: Hmm, would be helpful creating an issue about it there.